# Fetching variables through Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I am having problem fetching table through ajax. 
Here is my ajax function:

```
function search() {
    var JobFunction_Id=document.getElementById("JobFunction_Id").value;
    var JobFamily_Id=document.getElementById("JobFamily_Id").value;
    var flag=0;
    var newreq=createRequest();
    if(JobFunction_Id!='' && JobFamily_Id!='') { flag=1; }    

    if(flag==1) {    
        var url=("Talent_S_New.php?JobFunction_Id="+JobFunction_Id+"&      JobFamily_Id="+JobFamily_Id);

        newreq.onreadystatechange=function() {
              alert('hi');
              if(newreq.readyState==4 && newreq.status==200) {

                   if(newreq.responseText!='') {
                       document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML  =newreq.responseText; }
                    //else {    
                    // document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML  =newreq.responseText;                     
                    //}
              }
        }
        newreq.open("GET",url,true);
        newreq.send();
    }
}​
```

I am trying to fetch output variables with table info  from this page.

```
echo('<table style="border:1px solid red" >');
echo('<th>');
echo('First Name');
echo('</th>');
echo('<th>');
echo('Last Name');
echo('</th>');
echo('<tr>');
echo('<td style="border:1px solid red">');

foreach($Allemp as $key=>$value) {
   if (array_key_exists('Error', $Allemp))
   {    echo($value);   }
   else
   {    echo($value["Emp_FirstName"]);  }

   //echo('</td>');
   //echo('<td style="border:1px solid red">');

   if (array_key_exists('Error', $Allemp))
   {    echo($value);   }
   else
   {    echo($value["Emp_LastName"]);   }
}
echo('</td>');
echo('</tr>');
echo('</table>');
```

Without ajax above code works fine. You can observ`alert('hi')`. If I put that alert it goes into `if(newreq.readyState==4 && newreq.status==200)` loop and result will be shown for a second and disappers  again. I think it's going into foreach loop bcos it shows alert 5 times and displays result for a second and disappears. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: What do you see in your Javascript console when you log `newreq.readyState` and `newreq.status` instead of alerting 'hi'?

Comment: Your Javascript will not receive anything until the PHP code has finished executing, so it has nothing to do with it going into the foreach loop. What do you get if you just load the PHP script directly in the browser (go to the URL of the PHP script)? Do you see the `alert('hi')` if you put it inside the if-statement? Instead of the `document.getElementById('display_result')...` part, try `console.log('response text = '+ newreq.responseText)` and see what shows up in your browser console (usually hit F12 to see it).

Comment: hello jasper if i dont use "alert" i dont see anything it does not load outpage at all..well Travesty3 iam going to try your steps and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you marked this as jQuery, I'm pretty sure most of this can be changed to something close to:

```
var url=("Talent_S_New.php?Function_Id="+JobFunction_Id+"&JobFamily_Id="+JobFamily_Id);
$.ajax(url, {
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data, status) {
    alert("success!");
    $("#display_result").html(data); // Incoming data placed in 'display_result'
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    alert("error..");
  }
});
```

Whether this fixes your issue, I have no idea. But you marked it as jQuery and I don't see one jQuery call in your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply dear.. sorry i think its my mistake.. but i need to do it through javascript ajax not jquery

Answer (score 0):

Why not using jQuery AJAX ?

here's an example :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url:'Talent_S_New.php',
  data:$('form').serialize,
  complete: function() { alert('hi'); }
  success: function(data) {
      $('#display_result').html(data.responseText);
  } 
});
```